# function handle to function with multiple output and input variables in filedatastore

Tags: function, matlab, handle, datastore

I am trying to build a fileDatastore from multiple large files using a custom read function.
This should work like

```
fds = fileDatastore(location, 'ReadFcn', @fcn)
```

I use a cell array containing several fullfile strings for location, which should be fine.
I simply can't figure out how to handle the read function which has multiple input and output variables and looks like this:

```
[A, B, C] = function(filestring, x, y, z)
```

How can I make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an "[anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)" to do *part* of this. An anonymous function lets you adapt the prototype of the function, "binding" in values, so one piece of the puzzle is to do this:

```
x = 7; y = 42; z = -1;
fcn = @(filename) myfunction(filename, x, y, z);
```

This makes a function `fcn` which you can call like `fcn('somefile')` and the effect is `myfunction('somefile', 7, 42, -1)`.

Unfortunately, there's a twist - `fileDatastore` needs a function returning only a single output. This is not something you can fix with an anonymous function, so you'll need to write a function in a MATLAB code file that does something like this perhaps:

```
function out = wrapMyFunction(filename, x, y, z)
    [A,B,C] = myfunction(filename, x, y, z);
    out = {A,B,C};
end
```

And then use

```
fcn = @(filename) wrapMyFunction(filename, x, y, z);
```

Comment: Hello Edric, I tried that today and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help and the comprehensive explanation. Best wishes, Joe